# How to use Hibernate Spatial in Grails?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

I use Grails 2.4.5 and Hibernate 3.6.10.18 and want to use [Hibernate Spacial](http://www.hibernatespatial.org) with my MySql database.

Here is part of my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
repositories {
        mavenRepo 'http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools'
        mavenRepo 'http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository'
}

dependencies {
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"

    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'

    compile 'org.hibernatespatial:hibernate-spatial:1.1.1'
    compile 'org.hibernatespatial:hibernate-spatial-mysql:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.vividsolutions:jts:1.13'
}
```

Refresh-dependencies works fine. But when I do. grails run-app I get the following error:

```
|Running Grails application
Error |
2015-07-17 21:00:05,471 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.setJpaEntityName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.setJpaEntityName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    Line | Method
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.setJpaEntityName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.setJpaEntityName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.setJpaEntityName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

**How do I resolve this error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Bug-in-startup-when-upgrading-to-2-3-7-maybe-the-Single-DB-Multi-tenant-plugin-td4655550.html):

```
    compile("org.hibernatespatial:hibernate-spatial:1.1.1") { 
        excludes("hibernate-core") 
        excludes("javassist") 
    } 
    compile("org.hibernatespatial:hibernate-spatial-mysql:1.1.1") { 
        excludes("hibernate-core") 
        excludes("javassist") 
    }
```